# LDAP_search PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I need to do research in AD-PHP with LDAP, but every time I do not have success.

I'm filtering by sAMAccountName. When I use a user with simple name (**E.x.:** printer) everything is ok but when the name is not simple (**E.x.:** paulo.neves) it does not work.

Any ideas?

```
    $usuario = "paulo.neves";

    $base_dn = "ou=Administradores, dc=tiisa, dc=com, dc=br";

    $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(cn=*)(samaccountname=$usuario))";

    if (!($search=@ldap_search($connect, $base_dn, $filter))) {
    die("Unable to search ldap server");
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, which?

Comment: Is it possible that `.` is a reserved character for `$filter` and requires escaping?

Comment: Also, what do you define as "not simple"? Simple for you or the program? (as @Matt mentioned, could it be that if a username has a character like a `.` in it you/the program consider it not simple?)

Comment: must use this "." this is the default setting of all over 500 logins already have. I can not change

Comment: classify as simply logging in with just one word. and the other as being composed.

Comment: No one is saying to not use `.`. What we're saying is that the `.` character may be getting interpreted as a reserved character and would need to be escaped.

Comment: ok .. is that my english is bad. I am using the google translator.
how can I do to fix it .. I am capturing the log with him
    $_SERVER['LOGON_USER'];
and then looking in AD to feed a base MYSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute values are defined in [RFC4511](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.1.5). The octets that be used in an attribute value are defined by the syntax of the attribute type in question. If the syntax of `samAccountName` allows dot (`.`) characters without a requirement that said characters be escaped, then they need not be escaped.

It is always possible that the native language may require a character to be escaped.

- Use the `ldapsearch` command line tool to verify that the entries with dots in the `cn` value can be retrieved from the directory
- Just for grins, escape the dot in the attribute value by using "`\2e`"  instead of "`.`" and see what happens.
- probably not related to your problem, but if every entry has a `cn` attribute, there is no need to use the present filter component `cn=*` in the search filter

#### see also

- [Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/)

Comment: Thank you! I did it! WHAT was the last missing help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet that `.` has to be escaped.